# Delete user meta based on key value that is an array

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have a user meta key `prize` which is an array contains `prize type` and `prize date`.
The date in unix timestamp.
How I can delete the user meta by specify the prize date only?

Example code:

```
delete_user_meta( $userID, 'prize', $meta_value ); 
$meta_value = array(
    'prize' => array(
         // Add something here like prize date = 1506556467
    ) , 
);
```

Key value in the database look like this:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:17:"prize name";i:1;i:1506556467;}
```

Comment: What do you want to delete? You have specified data, f.e. "1506556467", and you want to delete user meta where prize data = 1506556467? Or what? Please clarify your point with more details

Comment: Yes, this what I want. I said in the question "How I can delete the user meta by specify the prize date only?". The criteria here is the prize date.

Answer (score 0):

As it is stored as serialized data you can't get and delete it with one single delete_user_meta() function.

You can do it with MYSQL query instead:

```
global $wpdb;
$userID=1;
$specified_date='1506556467';
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE from $wpdb->usermeta 
where user_id= %d 
and meta_key='prize' 
and meta_value like %s",$userID,'%'.$specified_date.'%'));
```